# DTM: How to add multiple class or multiple id in a selector?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I need to create a single event rule for the below anchor tags. I have 2 classes to add or i can use id.

```
    <a id="Message1" class="read">test1</a>
    <a id="Message2" class="unread">test2</a>
```

In my event rule i have added a as selector and then used custom code like below to capture id or class. Both dint work. What is the issue here?

if ( $(this).attr('id').indexof("Message") > 0 ) {return true;} else {return false;}

if ( $(this).attr('class') == "read"  || $(this).attr('class') == "unread" ) {return true;} else {return false;}

Comment: I have updated the selector with outer div and the the anchor tag and manually assigned the property "ID" as Message. (as regular expression) This works fine in chrome but it doesn't work in firefox. Please help. If i remove the property it works in both the browsers but all the anchor tag starts firing where i would like to restrict the anchor tag to one which has id that starts with Message.

Comment: firstly it's `indexOf` not `indexof` (notice the camelCase). 2nd, "Message" starts on index 0. Using `indexOf` on a string returns the character position of the substring within the string. Character positions in a string start at 0. So, your condition expects greater than 0, but your id is e.g. "Message1" so `indexOf` will return 0, because it matched, and the starting position of "Message" is index 0 of the string. You need to change it to `indexOf("Message")!=-1` or do a strict comparison `indexOf("Message")===0`